# Yii2 ActiveRecord how to get only populated attributes from model?

Tags: activerecord, yii2

When using an ActiveRecord to retrieve models it's possible to select a few columns. For example:

`Product::find()->select('product_id,name')->all();`

There are more columns than `product_id` and `name` in the database, but this example returns an array filled with all models, having only the `product_id` and `name` attributes filled. This is expected of course because I've passed them into `select()`.

Now when looping through the found models and calling `$model->getAttributes()` it returns an array of **all** model attributes and their values (`null` for the not-selected attributes), including all columns that were not selected in the query but are in the model's `attributes()` function.

Is there a way to call a function similar to `getAttributes()` but returning only the populated attributes that were selected in the query: `product_id` and `name`?

I know it's possible to pass in exclusions to `getAttributes()` but I'd rather have the populated attributes returned based on the values I've selected in the ActiveRecord query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your case you should be able to use [`fields()`](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-db-baseactiverecord#fields()-detail) method:

```
$attributes = $model->getAttributes($model->fields());
```

Note that `fields()` does not guarantee this behavior if you change model after find - unsetting (`unset($model->product_id)`) or setting (`$model->some_field = 'some value'`) attributes will affect result of `fields()`.